# Prevent Eclipse setting breakpoint on Scala anonymous functions (lambdas)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, scala, breakpoints

Using Scala plugin for Eclipse version 2.1 milestone 2, in Eclipse Indigo, if I set a breakpoint on a line that contains an anonymous function, e.g.

```
myList.map((x: String) => foo(bar(x)))
```

"the" breakpoint will be hit not only when `map` is called, but also when the anonymous function is called (it's actually multiple breakpoints, but frustratingly, they only show up as one breakpoint in the breakpoint tab in Eclipse). I think this is a regression, because I seem to remember you used to get multiple breakpoints showing up in this kind of case.

How can I stop Eclipse from treating the anonymous function as part of the same breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoints are line-based, so just add newlines in such a way that it's still syntactically valid, but the lambdas you don't want to hit are now on separate lines. E.g.

```
myList.map(
  (x: String) => foo(bar(x)))
```

(In my case, I still see an apparently spurious double-hit on the line, but that seems to be a different issue - it's not hitting the lambdas any more.)